# WebPack building JavaScript bundle causes application errors when running

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I have an existing, Live website running an Angular 1.6.45 application. This is being built using WebPack 4.12.0.

I recently made some changes to the application, added some new controllers to the application and now the WebPack build output is causing the application to error when running.

Console errors read like: `angular.js:15018 TypeError: $ is not a function at TownPickerDirective.link (TownPickerDirective.js:18)` - TownPickerDirective hasn't been touched for about a year!

I've spotted in the WebPack bundle.js file that it is creating addtional `/* harmony import */` entries for a couple of directives, which it wasn't doing the last time it was built (about 4 months ago), which I suspect is the cause of the web site errors.

Live bundle.js Output:
`/* harmony import */ var _prerequisites_TownPickerDirective__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./prerequisites/TownPickerDirective */ "./Scripts/app/prerequisites/TownPickerDirective.ts");`

Current (breaking) bundle.js Output:
`/* harmony import */ var _prerequisites_TownPickerDirective__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./prerequisites/TownPickerDirective */ "./Scripts/app/prerequisites/TownPickerDirective.js"); /* harmony import */ var _prerequisites_TownPickerDirective__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_prerequisites_TownPickerDirective__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__);`

I've rolled out all the changes made recently in an attempt to get the site building properly again, but the output still causes errors. There have been no WebPack config changes and the additions to the app.ts are just registering controllers.

Any ideas?